# How to set ArrayList of CustomObject for AutoCompleteTextView in android?

Tags: android, search, filter, arraylist, autocompletetextview

I am trying to implement Search feature for my android app.So, I am using `AutoCompleteTextView`. But, I am using ArrayList of custom Object.

This is my class.

```
public class Vehicle
{
 private String model,manufacturer;
}
```

Now, I have ArrayList of these Vehicle objects.

My question is, How to use these arraylist of objects to set as adapter for `AutoCompleteTextView` to search for `model` ??

Answer (score 2):

> How to use these arraylist of objects to set as adapter for
>   AutoCompleteTextView to search for model ??

You don't say what do you show from the `Vehicle` class. The simplest way to setup the `AutoCompletTextView` is to use the simple `ArrayAdapter`(which will only show one value from `Vehicle`, the model) and also modify the `Vehicle` class like this:

```
public class Vehicle {
 private String model, manufacturer;

 @Override
 public String toString() {
    return model;
 }
}
```

Then simply give the list of custom `Vehicle` objects to the `ArrayAdapter` and set the  adapter on the `AutoCompleTextView`.

For anything more complex then this you'll need to provide more details.